# Code working on one compiler but failing on the other

Tags: typescript

The typescript playground is giving me the following errors:

> No
> overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn:
> (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[])
> => T, initialValue: T): T', gave the following error.
> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T[]'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue:
> never[], currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) =>
> never[], initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.
> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'.

and

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.

[image]

```
function myFilter<T>(arr: T[], cb: (v: T) => boolean): T[] {
      const a = arr.reduce(
        (acc, val) => (cb(val) === true ? [...acc, val] : acc),
        []
      );
      return a;
    }
    
    const c = myFilter([1, 3, 4, 5], (v) => v === 3);
    
    console.log(c);
```

I'm using : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play
But when i use : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-xt7e2y

Everything is fine and i get no errors? Why is the official typescript playground complaining and how do i fix it? or is it just a bug?

Comment: Why not just use `arr.filter(cb)`?

Comment: I'm doing it this way for learning purposes, i could simply use filter but the challenge was to create my own filter function using reduce @jsejcksn

Comment: Ah, good luck on your learning! You might also try a version using a loop like this: https://tsplay.dev/NaYvyN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version or config is used in `stackbliz` so it is hard to say why you are not getting error.

However, the problem is in empty array because empty array, by the default, is infered as `never[]`.

In order to fix this error, you need to use explicit argument for `reduce`.

```js
function myFilter<T>(arr: T[], cb: (v: T) => boolean): T[] {
    const a = arr.reduce<T[]>( // TS is aware now that [] is T[]
        (acc, val) => cb(val) === true ? [...acc, val] : acc,
        []
    );
    return a;
}

const c = myFilter([1, 3, 4, 5], (v) => v === 3);

console.log(c);
```